# local variable referenced before assignment PYTHON

Tags: python

Buen dia, al ejecutar este codigo me aparece el error de local variable referenced before assigment.
La funcion deberia devolverme un objeto instaciado de clase vechiculo y tener los atributos de color y tipo y el metodo acelerar.
¿Donde estaría mi error?

```
def ClaseVehiculo(tipo, color):
    Vehiculo 
    class Vehiculo(tipo, color):
        def __init__(self, tipo, color):
            self.tipo = tipo
            self.color = color
            self.velocidad = 0

        def Acelerar(self, acelerar):

            self.velocidad = self.velocidad + acelerar
    
            if((self.velocidad) <= 0):
                return 0
        
            elif((self.velocidad) >= 100):
                return 100
        
            else:
                return self.velocidad
```

Comment: Escribiste la palabra Vehiculo al principio de la función. Python cree que tratas de acceder a una variable llamada Vehiculo la cual no existe. Cual es el proposito? Si no tiene proposito, hay que sacarla. Si es un comentario, debe estar precedido por #. Edición: Incluso solucionando ese problema, ocurrirá un nuevo error, ya que estás tratando de hacer herencia multiple (lo que pones en los parentesis a la derecha de class Vehiculo) recurriendo también a variables inexistentes. No creo que quieras usar herencia multiple para este caso. Yo repasaría como crear una clase.

Comment: De cualquier modo, más por curiosidad y deseo de ayudarte a mejorar, por que creas una clase dentro de una función? Yo lo he hecho una vez, pero nunca me fue necesario realmente.

Comment: Creo una clase por que la función me pide que devuelva un objeto instanciado de la clase vehículo, puede ser que este entendiendo mal el ejercicio y que no sea necesario la clase dentro de la función

Comment: En tal caso, como quedaria el codigo?

Comment: SI te piden una función que retorna la instancia de una clase solo debes de crear la instancia dentro de la función, no crear toda la clase dentro de la función. Saca la clase de la función y dentro de la función solo coloca `return Vehiculo(tipo, color)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

- Una clase no necesita estar dentro de una función para poder crear una instancia. Las clases habitualmente (el comportamiento puede ser cambiado con metaclases) se pueden instanciar llamandolas directamente. En realidad, **es mucho más complejo que esto**, pero digamos que cuando llamas a una clase así `Vehiculo(...)` estás en realidad haciendo `Vehiculo.__init__(instancia de Vehiculo, ...)`
- La palabra Vehiculo al principio de la función simplemente no tiene sentido, ya que intentas acceder a una variable llamada así, la cual no existe. No se el proposito de esto: si fue accidental o querías poner un comentario. Si era lo segundo, tiene que estár precedido por # para que Python sepa que se trata de un comentario: `# Vehiculo`
- Cuando creas una clase, así `class clase(...)`, NO estás indicando los argumentos que recibe (eso se haría en el método `__init__`). Eso que le pones Python lo toma como herencia multiple. Un tema un poco más avanzado si recien empiesas con clases.
- `__init__` debe recibir un primer argumento, que será la instancia de Vehiculo recien salida del horno.

Lo demás está bien, solo te diría que lo común y lo convencional sería que los nombres de métodos, atributos y variables estén en minuscula.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
# Vehiculo 
# Quité la herencia multiple
class Vehiculo:
    # agregue el parametro self.
    def __init__(self, tipo, color):
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.color = color
        self.velocidad = 0

    def Acelerar(self, acelerar):

        self.velocidad = self.velocidad + acelerar

        if((self.velocidad) <= 0):
            return 0
    
        elif((self.velocidad) >= 100):
            return 100
    
        else:
            return self.velocidad

instancia_vehiculo = Vehiculo("camioneta", "rojo")
instancia_vehiculo.Acelerar(10)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la expliacion!

Comment: De nada Juan c: Agradecería que aceptes alguna de las respuestas presentes. Y si te fueron utiles también puedes votarlas :D

Answer (score 0):

Has escrito nombre de la clase al inicio de la función sin antes instanciarla, por eso el error dice que la variable fue llamada antes de ser creada (porque efectivamente asi es). Si quieres crear un objeto de la clase Vehiculo dentro de un funcion, puedes hacerlo asi:

```py
class Vehiculo():
    def __init__(self, tipo, color):
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.color = color
        self.velocidad = 0

     def Acelerar(self, acelerar):
        self.velocidad = self.velocidad + acelerar
           if((self.velocidad) <= 0):
               return 0
        
           elif((self.velocidad) >= 100):
               return 100
        
           else:
               return self.velocidad

def CreateVehiculo(tipo, color):
    # aqui instancia la clase vehiculo y crea el objeto
    vehiculo1 = Vehiculo(tipo, color) 
    return vehiculo1

# aqui invocas la funcion que crea la instancia
vehiculo1 = CreateVehiculo('Nissan', 'Rojo')

# ahora ya puedes invocar cualquier metodo del objeto vehiculo1..
```

Ojo, cree una funcion para instanciar el objeto, pero puedes crearlo directamente sin usar una funcion, siempre y cuando sea creado luego de la definicion de la clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion!